# MongoDB object field and range query index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following structure in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : {
       "user" : 14197,
       "date" : ISODate("2014-10-24T00:00:00.000Z")
    },
...
}
```

I have a performance problem when I try to select data by user & date-range. Monogo doesn't use index & runs full-scan over collection.

```
db.timeuse.daily.find({ "_id.user": 289006, "_id.date" : {$gt: ISODate("2014-10-23T00:00:00Z"), $lte: ISODate("2014-10-30T00:00:00Z")}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 6,
    "nscannedObjects" : 66967,
    "nscanned" : 66967,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 66967,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 66967,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 523,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1392,
    "server" : "mongo-shard0003:27018",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
    "type" : "COLLSCAN",
        "works" : 66969,
        "yields" : 523,
        "unyields" : 523,
        "invalidates" : 16,
        "advanced" : 6,
        "needTime" : 66962,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "docsTested" : 66967,
        "children" : [ ]
},
    "millis" : 1392
}
```

So far I found only one way - use $in.

```
db.timeuse.daily.find({"_id": { $in: [
    {"user": 289006, "date": ISODate("2014-10-23T00:00:00Z")},
    {"user": 289006, "date": ISODate("2014-10-24T00:00:00Z")}
]}}).explain()



{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "user" : 289006,
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-10-23T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                    "user" : 289006,
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-10-23T00:00:00Z")
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "user" : 289006,
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-10-24T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                    "user" : 289006,
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-10-24T00:00:00Z")
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
```

If there's a more elegant way to run this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't put your data in the `_id` field and use a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/): `db.timeuse.daily.ensureIndex( { "user" : 1, "date": 1 } )`.

Explanation:
You're abusing the `_id` key convention, or more precisely the fact that MongoDB can index entire objects. What you want to achieve requires **index intersection or a compound index**, that is, either two separate indexes that can be combined (that feature is called [index intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) and by now, it should be available in MongoDB, but it has limitations) or a special index for the set of keys which in MongoDB is called a compound index.

The `_id` field is indexed by default, but it's indexed as a whole, i.e. **the `_id` index with only support equality queries on the entire object**, rather than parts of the object. That also explains why the `$in` query works.

In general, that data structure with the default index will behave oddly. Consider this:

```
> db.sort.insert({"_id" : {"name" : "foo", value : 1} });
> db.sort.insert({"_id" : {"name" : "foo", value : 1, bla : "foo"} });
> db.sort.find();
{ "_id" : { "name" : "foo", "value" : 4343 } }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "foo", "value" : 4343, "bla" : "fooffo" } }

> db.sort.find({"_id" : {"name" : "foo", value : 4343} }); 
{ "_id" : { "name" : "foo", "value" : 4343 } }
// no second result here...
```

Imagine MongoDB basically hashed the entire object and was simply looking for the object hash - such an index can't support range queries based on some part of the hash.

Comment: I added compound index:
 `db.timeuse.daily.ensureIndex( { "_id.user": 1, "_id.date": 11 })`